# Installing 64 bit version Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 64-bit

I have a 3GB DDR2 computer and it is compatible for 64 bit OS. But I have heard only on 4GB system Ill be able to see measurable performance (in windows environment). So should i stick with my 32 bit or can i run the 64 bit version fine???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. If you're using a 64bit processor, use 64bit Ubuntu! For sure, you can run Ubuntu 64bit fine.

Comment: But will i be seeing any performance change?

Comment: You might see a little bit performance change but you can get more advantages if using 64bit Ubuntu instead of 32bit.